# Fiware IoT Agent UL: Send command_value via mqtt to device

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am using the IoT-agent for ultra light and I'd like to send a command (including a specific value) back to my IoT-Device. If I follow the example for a smart door [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-over-MQTT#opening-the-smart-door) I can send something like:

```
curl -iX PATCH \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002/attrs' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
    "color": {
    "type" : "command",
    "value" : "100"
    }
  }'
```

Fiware publishes the payload "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002@color|" to my mqtt-broker. But I would expect the value of "100" to be passed as well?

I also found [this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/docs/usermanual.md#commands) documentation on Git regarding mqtt-commands. But that one does not specify where to send that and how? I suppose it uses the the same URL as [this](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-over-MQTT#seven-request) request: http://localhost:4041/v1/updateContext
?? Is that the up-to-date way to issue commands?

I am using Orion-ld and the iotagent-ul:1.8.0.

Can somebody help me getting the value of "color" into the mqtt-message as well?

Thank you!

**EDIT1:**

I just tried orion:2.2.0 and reregistered the command like this:

```
{
  "description": "Setting LED",
  "dataProvided": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", "type": "pysense"
      }
    ],
    "attrs": ["color", "brightness"]
  },
  "provider": {
    "http": {"url": "http://orion:1026/v2"},
    "legacyForwarding": true
  }
}
```

If i try to send the command orion-logs go crazy (keep scrolling) with the following text:

```
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  logMsg.h[1844]: Starting transaction from 172.18.1.1:35800/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002/attrs
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  rest.cpp[885]: Service Path 0: '/dresden'
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  connectionOperations.cpp[239]: Database Operation Successful (count: { _id.id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", _id.servicePath: { $in: [ /^/dresden$/ ] } })
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  connectionOperations.cpp[94]: Database Operation Successful (query: { _id.id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", _id.servicePath: { $in: [ /^/dresden$/ ] } })
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  connectionOperations.cpp[94]: Database Operation Successful (query: { $or: [ { entities.id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", $or: [ { entities.type: "pysense" }, { entities.type: { $exists: false } } ], entities.isPattern: "false", entities.isTypePattern: { $ne: true }, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] } }, { entities.isPattern: "true", entities.isTypePattern: { $ne: true }, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... }, { entities.isPattern: "false", entities.isTypePattern: true, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... }, { entities.isPattern: "true", entities.isTypePattern: true, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... } ] })
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  connectionOperations.cpp[177]: Database Operation Successful (query: { query: { $or: [ { contextRegistration.entities: { $in: [ { id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", type: "pysense" }, { type: "pysense", id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002" } ] } }, { contextRegistration.entities.id: { $in: [] } } ], expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, contextRegistration.attrs.name: { $in: [ "color" ] }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^/dresden$/ ] } }, orderby: { _id: 1 } })
fiware-orion   | ERROR@06:42:33  postUpdateContext.cpp[553]: Internal Error (attribute 'color' not found)
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  logMsg.h[1844]: Starting transaction to http://orion:1026/v1/updateContext
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  httpRequestSend.cpp[592]: Sending message 8 to HTTP server: sending message of 433 bytes to HTTP server
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  logMsg.h[1844]: Starting transaction from 172.18.1.7:46738/v1/updateContext
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  rest.cpp[885]: Service Path 0: '/dresden'
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:33  connectionOperations.cpp[94]: Database Operation Successful (query: { _id.id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", _id.type: "pysense", _id.servicePath: { $in: [ /^/dresden$/ ] } })
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:34  connectionOperations.cpp[94]: Database Operation Successful (query: { $or: [ { entities.id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", $or: [ { entities.type: "pysense" }, { entities.type: { $exists: false } } ], entities.isPattern: "false", entities.isTypePattern: { $ne: true }, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] } }, { entities.isPattern: "true", entities.isTypePattern: { $ne: true }, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... }, { entities.isPattern: "false", entities.isTypePattern: true, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... }, { entities.isPattern: "true", entities.isTypePattern: true, expiration: { $gt: 1559716953 }, status: { $ne: "inactive" }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^$|^/#$|^/dresden/#$|^/dresden$/, null ] }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... } ] })
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:34  connectionOperations.cpp[177]: Database Operation Successful (query: { query: { $or: [ { contextRegistration.entities: { $in: [ { id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", type: "pysense" }, { type: "pysense", id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002" } ] } }, { contextRegistration.entities.id: { $in: [] } } ], expiration: { $gt: 1559716954 }, contextRegistration.attrs.name: { $in: [ "color" ] }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^/dresden$/ ] } }, orderby: { _id: 1 } })
fiware-orion   | INFO@06:42:34  logMsg.h[1844]: Starting transaction to http://orion:1026/v1/updateContext
...
```

And I get the following error as a reply in Postman:

```
{
    "error": "NotFound",
    "description": "The requested entity has not been found. Check type and id"
}
```

When orion registers the command by itself it looks like this with the iot-agent as provider instead of orion/v1:

```
    {
        "id": "5cf677b7c7ecc4737e1e0ec9",
        "expires": "2020-06-04T13:52:55.00Z",
        "dataProvided": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002",
                    "type": "pysense"
                }
            ],
            "attrs": [
                "color",
                "brightness"
            ]
        },
        "provider": {
            "http": {
                "url": "http://iot-agent:4041"
            },
            "supportedForwardingMode": "all",
            "legacyForwarding": true
        },
        "status": "active"
    }
```

With that I can actually send a command but it still misses the value. :(

**EDIT2:**
Something I found in the extensive debug logs of orion:

```
fiware-orion   | INFO@07:35:09  connectionOperations.cpp[177]: Database Operation Successful (query: { query: { $or: [ { contextRegistration.entities: { $in: [ { id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002", type: "pysense" }, { type: "pysense", id: "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002" } ] } }, { contextRegistration.entities.id: { $in: [] } } ], expiration: { $gt: 1559720109 }, contextRegistration.attrs.name: { $in: [ "color" ] }, servicePath: { $in: [ /^/dresden$/ ] } }, orderby: { _id: 1 } })
fiware-orion   | ERROR@07:35:09  postUpdateContext.cpp[553]: Internal Error (attribute 'color' not found)
```

After that the IoT-Agent updates the context but without a value.

Comment: Have you tested the same scenario with official Orion instead of Orion-LD (for instance Orion 2.2.0)? Does it work with it or the behavior is the same? Thx!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it simply by changing the docker-compose and forcing a recreate. Is that sufficent? Because it kind of yields the same result. I will edit the first post with detailed information for better readability.

Comment: In order to check if you are using the right Orion, could you do a `GET /version` on the CB port and tell what response you get, pls? Thx!

Comment: The response is
```
{
"orion" : {
  "version" : "2.2.0",
  "uptime" : "0 d, 3 h, 59 m, 37 s",
  "git_hash" : "5a46a70de9e0b809cce1a1b7295027eea0aa757f",
  "compile_time" : "Mon Feb 25 15:15:27 UTC 2019",
  "compiled_by" : "root",
  "compiled_in" : "37fdc92c3e97",
  "release_date" : "Mon Feb 25 15:15:27 UTC 2019",
  "doc" : "https://fiware-orion.rtfd.io/en/2.2.0/"
}
}
```

Comment: Hey fgalan, I found a solution to my problem! I will edit it into my initial Post. Thank you for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Great to know you solved! But instead including the solution in the question itself, I'd recommend you to self-answer it. I mean, cut-and-paste that part from question post to answer. This is the usual way of doing in SOF.

Comment: Could you test again with PATCH adding the type of the entity to the request? I mean to use `http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002/attrs?type=pysense` and tell me if it works, pls? Thanks!

Comment: Hey fgalan, I will change the post accordingly. Thanks for the advice! 
I also tried your suggested method with ?type=pysense and it indeed works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two fixes to that problem. First thing that differs from the tutorial is the provider you need to register with a command. Instead of orion:1026/v1 register the IoT-Agent. It should look something like this with the IOTA_PROVIDER_URL from your docker-compose.yml as provider:

```
{
        "description": "Setting LED",
        "dataProvided": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002",
                    "type": "pysense"
                }
            ],
            "attrs": [
                "color",
                "brightness"
            ]
        },
        "provider": {
            "http": {
                "url": "http://iot-agent:4041"
            },
            "supportedForwardingMode": "all",
            "legacyForwarding": true
        },
        "status": "active"
    }
```

Now you can send a command in two ways. The first one is directly to the north port of the IoT Agent with a POST command to orion/v1/updateContext. The second one is to update the command in the context by sending a PATCH command to the entities attributes, providing the type of the entity to the request.

**1: POST to updateContext**

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:1026/v1/updateContext' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "pysense",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:pysense:002",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "color",
                    "type": "command",
                    "value": "25"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "UPDATE"
}
```

**2: PATCH adding the type of the entity**

```
curl -iX PATCH \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn_ngsi-ld:pysense:002/attrs?type=pysense' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "color": {
      "type" : "command",
      "value" : "90"
  }
}
```

Thanks to fgalan for the help with that!

Comment: Regarding PATCH, it is documented the need for using entity type. From https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/context_providers/index.html: "On forwarding, any type of entity in the NGSIv2 update/query matches registrations without entity type. However, the opposite doesn't work, so if you have registrations with types, then you must use `?type` in NGSIv2 update/query in order to obtain a match"