# FIWARE Orion error 'Couldn't connect to server' forwarding 'Query' to providing application

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion, iota

I am trying to provision a device and send actuation commands back using 2 components Orion and LoRaWAN IoT Agent.

I am running Orion and other components on docker-compose file, and the IoT Agent using `node bin/iotagent-lora`

I have successfully provisioned the device using :

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:4061/iot/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: agriculture' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /irrigation' \
  -d '{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "pycom1",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:tempHumid:001",
      "entity_type": "tempHumid",
      "transport": "MQTT",

      "attributes": [
        {
    "object_id": "temperature",

          "name": "deviceState",
          "type": "Text"
        }],
      "commands": [
        {  

          "name": "on",
        "type": "command"
      },
        {       
          "name": "off"
        ,"type": "command"
      }
       ],
        "internal_attributes": {
        "lorawan": {
          "application_server": {
            "host": "10.8.244.180",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin",
            "provider": "loraserver.io"
          },
          "dev_eui": "0097da62c6b67443",
          "app_eui": "70B3D57ED000985F",
          "application_id": "1",
          "application_key": "2b043fb00af7c6ac4075a35b8a18fc9c",
          "data_model":"application_server"
        }}}]}'
```

an automatic registrations is created in Orion after provisioning the device:

```
{
    "id": "5d2d9f4f795d881c2355ab7c",
    "expires": "2020-07-16T09:56:31.00Z",
    "dataProvided": {
        "entities": [{
            "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:tempHumid:001",
            "type": "tempHumid"
        }],
        "attrs": ["on", "off"]
    },
    "provider": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://localhost:4061"
        },
        "supportedForwardingMode": "all",
        "legacyForwarding": true
    },
    "status": "active"
}
```

Following this [tutorial](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-over-mqtt/index.html#enabling-context-broker-commands) I have created another registration for actuation commands like the following:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/registrations' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: agriculture' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /irrigation' \
  -d '{
  "description": "Pump Commands",
  "dataProvided": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:tempHumid:001", 

        "type": "tempHumid"
      }
    ],
    "attrs": [ "on", "off" ]
  },
  "provider": {
    "http": {"url": "http://localhost:1026/v1"},
    "legacyForwarding": true
  }
}'
```

I have tried to use the proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427851/fiware-iot-agent-ul-send-command-value-via-mqtt-to-device) to an issue similar to the one I am facing, and after trying, I have obtained this error:

```
{"error":"NotFound","description":"The requested entity has not been found. Check type and id"}
```

while Orion reported

> fiware-orion Starting transaction to http://localhost:4061//updateContext

I don't know if it is linked to this issue but a similar bug (double slash in url) was already reported in [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2141)

```
fiware-orion   | INFO@10:16:34  logMsg.h[1844]: Starting transaction to http://localhost:4061//updateContext
fiware-orion   | INFO@10:16:34  httpRequestSend.cpp[592]: Sending message 4 to HTTP server: sending message of 447 bytes to HTTP server
fiware-orion   | ERROR@10:16:34  postUpdateContext.cpp[190]: Runtime Error (error 'Couldn't connect to server' forwarding 'Update' to providing application)
fiware-orion   | INFO@10:16:34  logMsg.h[1874]: Transaction ended
```

Thank you in advance